# In neo4j how to return specific nodes or relationship with cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

You are given two arrays one for some labels and another for some relationships and you are asked to return the nodes and their relationships which are found only in the arrays you where given. I tried different approach to it but I couldn't get a better cipher to return the graph with respect to both arrays

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) where n in ["username"] and r in ["knows"] return n,r
```

The code above, I know its completely wrong but it kinda shows the idea, share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WHERE ANY(l IN labels(n) WHERE l IN ['username','label2'])
      AND type(r) IN ['knows','relType2']
RETURN n,r,m
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but also I was wondering if there is a better way to return data because if one of the arrays is empty nothing is returned regardless if another array have some contents

Comment: then you can use  OR instead of AND